# c++ store address of next position of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have an array that I want to store the address of the next array in the current position.

So far I have

```
char *a = new char[50];
char *free = a;

*a = &(a + 1); //value of a[0] is equal to the address of a[1]
```

Also I'm using a `char` array so I'm sure I'll need to cast some stuff.
Any help would be nice.

Comment: You can't store a `char*` in a `char`. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: pointer math... a = a++;

Comment: `a = a++;` causes undefined behavior even in simple types. Could you tell us again what you're trying to do? You can do *pointer math* with the variables in one array and the pointers in another, and you can do *one variable points to another within an array* by using **indices** rather than pointers.

Answer (score 3):

You can't store a char* in a char array.

A character is equal to one byte.  The size of a pointer, such as char*, varies depending on your computer.  On my computer, its 8 bytes.  8 bytes can't fit in 1 byte.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "sizeof(char): " << sizeof(char) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(char*): " << sizeof(char*) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

// Outputs 
// sizeof(char): 1
// sizeof(char*): 8
```

You also won't be able to cast a char* to a char to fit it in the array either, as your compiler will yell at you.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char myArray[10];
    std::cout << (char)&myArray[0];
}

// Compiler error:
// g++ main.cpp -std=gnu++11
// main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
// main.cpp:7:34: error: cast from ‘char*’ to ‘char’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
```

The closest thing you can do to get this working is to use an array of size_t.  size_t is the size of a pointer.  So the number of bytes in size_t and size_t* is equal, and therefore you can put a size_t* in an array of size_t... after casting.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    size_t myArray[10];
    myArray[0] = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&myArray[1]);

    std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << myArray[0] << std::endl;
}
// Outputs: 0x7fff4eded5c8
```

Also, consider using indicies[] instead of pointer addition.  Its more readable, and it does the same thing under the hood.  a[1] == *(a+1).

Comment: `std::size_t` is not the size of a pointer. `std::uintptr_t` is.